# jfugue - Controlling the volume of the pattern

Tags: java, volume, jfugue

I'm trying to control the volume of a pattern. From the documentation I found this:

```
X[Volume]=10200;
```

which they mentioned controls the volume. I'm not sure how to use this. Should I declare something to use this? From what I understand this is a 'Controller' functionality. Below is my code.

```
import org.jfugue.*;

public class masterVolume {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        Player player = new Player();
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C D E F G A B");
        player.play(pattern);

        X[Volume]=10200; //error    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! That works! If you can post this as an answer, I will mark it as right answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should pass it to the MIDI controller like so:

```
    Pattern pattern = new Pattern(" X[Volume]=10200 C D E F G A B");
```

Comment: Validated by the author of JFugue :)

Comment: not working for me. Pattern pattern1 = new Pattern(" X[Volume]=2000 C D E");
new Player().play(pattern1);
        
Pattern pattern2 = new Pattern(" X[Volume]=10200 C D E");
new Player().play(pattern2);  --> This two have the same volume in my laptop